# MVC4 OAuthWebSecurity unknown method RegisterClient after upgrading DotNetOpenAuth to 4.3.0.13117

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

Before I upgraded I was using custom oauth clients, after upgrading the DotNetOpenAuth nuget packs I now get an error of "unknown method RegisterClient" when calling OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient.  It worked fine before upgrading, here is the code snippet.

```
var extraData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
extraData.Add("Icon", "/../../Images/Login/google.png");            
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
    client: new CustomGoogleClient(OAuthSettings.GoogleClientID, OAuthSettings.GoogleSecretID), displayName: "Google", extraData: extraData);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry any issues this question might have cause, I fixed it by completely removing DotNetOpenAuth and reinstalled the package.